# Change Temporary Directory

Tags: files-and-directories, kernel, system-modeler

How to change the value of $TemporaryDirectory ? I need to change it because there is not enough space on the C drive and the calculation seems to stop after a while !

Comment: TempDir is the default directory for windows and not only for mathematica. It seems mathematica doesn't create anything automatically in this directory except using createdirectory and so on without specific path. Are you sure that mathematica writes right in this directory? The simplest thing you can try to redirect input is to use setdirectory to the folder that you want.

Comment: What kind of operation do you have problems with?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basics of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. When you see good ones, please vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. As you receive help, try to give it too, by *answering questions* in your area of expertise.

Comment: If you are in Windows, on System Properties, Environment Variables, you could change the TMP and TEMP variables to point to other folders. But do this carefully and only after understanding what you are doing. Anyhow, this seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and its likely to be closed.

Comment: [`$TemporaryDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$TemporaryDirectory.html) gives the main system directory for temporary files on your computer system. Its reporting a system variable, not defining where it should be.

Comment: I do not really get the downvote. The question does raise an interesting point (even if most users never come across the issue).

Comment: Yves Klett: It is a simulation in SystemModeler and the iteration process is done in Mathematica

Comment: Perhaps you should add that info to the question, and add the system-modeler tag as well.

Comment: @rhermans Michaels answer seems to contradict your statement somewhat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `$TemporaryDirectory` to a desired directory.  You can use system commands such as [`FileNameJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FileNameJoin.html) or [`FileNameSetter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FileNameSetter.html) to create a directory name appropriate to your system.  I have a unix-based Mac, so I ran an example using

```
$TemporaryDirectory = "/tmp/math"
```

Here is the example from the docs for [`OpenWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenWrite.html), executed under this new setting.

> Create and open a new stream for writing:

```
fname = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "testfile"}];

s = OpenWrite[fname]

(* OutputStream["/tmp/math/testfile", 145] *)
```

> Write an expression to the stream:

```
Write[s, Expand[(x + y)^10]]
```

> Close the stream:

```
Close[s]

(* "/tmp/math/testfile" *)
```

And so on.

**Caveat:**  On my system, the temporary directory used for

```
s = OpenWrite[]
```

(from the docs for [`$TemporaryDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$TemporaryDirectory.html)) is **not** `$TemporaryDirectory`, but some file in a random-looking sub-sub-directory: `"/var/folders/9d/68khy4s15sjf9qfpnhqz9tnc0000gn/T/m000003840331"`.

Comment: What version of Mma are you running? According to the docs, prior to 7.0 the value of `$TemporaryPrefix` was used for `OpenWrite[]` and `CreateDirectory[]`.

Comment: @dionys V10.0.1, Mac OSX 10.9.5.  Good call - it is in fact `$TemporaryPrefix` that's being used.  Am I the only one?

Comment: It is the same on my system, V10.0.1, Windows x64 .. defaults determined by $TemporaryPrefix (despite what's stated in the docs).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from Mathematica Forum on Wolfram website.

"If you wish to change the value of $TemporaryDirectory for a particular Mathematica session then you can simply execute

```
$TemporaryDirectory="path to a new directory"
```

since $TemporaryDirectory is not Protected"

Thanks to David Reiss

Comment: Um, that's what I said...

Comment: You should consider accepting @MichaelE2´s answer - he proposed the same solution 12hrs earlier...

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. Yes, you're right. 
Sorry, I'm new here. I didn't know that there is "accept answer" button.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to Vote up your answer :(